# Regex to extract host

Tags: regex

i've searched all over the net for this but does anyone have a Regular expression to extract the host from this text?

```
Host: my.domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

With capturing group (you have to retrieve the value from group 1 afterwards):

```
Host:\s*(.*)$
```

With lookbehind (doesn't work in most regex engines due to variable-length lookbehind, but the match itself is the value you want):

```
(?<=Host:\s*).*$
```

Comment: The trailing `\s*` is superfluous - it will never participate in the match because the greedy `.*` has already consumed the entire string. Same for the lookaround version (also, here the `\s*` part of the lookbehind assertion will never participate in the match)

Comment: Hm, you're right. Then that makes accounting fo trailing LWS a bit more difficult ;-) – screw the spec then, I'm lazy.

Comment: I guess `(?<=Host:\s*).*?(?=\s*)$` should work, then. Ah well.

Comment: Not quite, because the regex finds the leftmost match, even if you make the star lazy. Also, you need to move  the `$` inside the lookahead assertion. Tricky stuff, these regexes :)

Comment: Ah, I'll just give up now. I don't usually answer regex questions without testing anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

check if this helps you

```
 function fnGetDomain(url) 
 {
    return (url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1]).replace('www.','');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+$)
```